# How do I get Air to remember the file path?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have tried:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('');
```

and

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('myFolder');
```

Which seems to be how people recommend how to do it when searching for this. These work when I am testing the movie but when I publish the Air file it stops working and just defaults to the computer root folder everytime.

If anyone can shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

**Additional information**

This is getting fustrating now. Here is the code in context. If anyone has any further ideas  it would be a big help I just can't work it out it all works fine apart from remembering the file path.

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(""));


videoselect1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectVideos);

       function selectVideos(evt:MouseEvent):void {

            file.addEventListener(FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, file_selectMultiple);
            file.browseForOpenMultiple("Please select a file or three...");
        }

      function file_selectMultiple(evt:FileListEvent):void {


            for (var i:uint = 0; i < evt.files.length; i++) {
                videostr += evt.files[i].nativePath + "\n";
                videopath.push(evt.files[i].nativePath);                    
                videoFiles = (evt.files.length);

            }
            video1output.text = ("You have selected " + videoFiles + " files" + "\n" + "\n" + videostr);



            }
```

I did have `file = new File();` in the selectVideos function but removing it meant at least it was going to the documents directory.

Comment: Could you add some detail please? The way you are doing it is correct. Could you post what the expected path is and what the actual path is in both debug and release builds?

Comment: I certainly can. The path in debug is: D:\Documents\Designs\SentIntoSpace\Flash\Application\Data Files 05022014
and the release build well if I just copy the path is "Computer". So it is going to the "My Computer" folder where you choose which drive, not even going to a hard drive. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tested it on other computers and they have the same issue.

Comment: The path in debug is actually incorrect as well for `applicationStorageDirectory`. Should be (off the top of my head, I'm on a Mac right now) `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\<your app id>`, though it might be slightly different depending on your Windows install. Regardless, I am at a loss why it is evaluating to `Computer`. I've built numerous AIR desktop apps and never had such an issue.

Comment: Hmm well at least I know the method is correct. Thanks for your input it's a starting block at least knowing that the paths coming out are incorrect.

Comment: Try installing on a different system. It looks like you've customized where your Documents folder is (different drive, different folder names) and that may be part of the issue. Try getting on a different machine and testing there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adobe AIR file path on MAC and widows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641203/adobe-air-file-path-on-mac-and-widows)